How to translate my Vietnamese name to Korean meaning or Korean-like name (like Korean people)?
My name is Phạm Nguyễn Ngọc Đạt, literally Chinese (particularly Cantonese would be closer in pronunciation) 范阮玉達 (or from Vietnamese to Korean sound like word by word is 팜 응웬 응옥 닷 by my King Sejong Korean teacher) (Most Vietnamese individual characters from the names are Chinese-like word, how do I translate to Korean meaning or Korean-like name (like Korean people)?

Can I ask - are both Phạm and Nguyễn your combined họ? I assume your tên đệm is Ngọc and that your tên chính is Đạt.

Exactly, Michaelyus. My father's surname is Phạm, and my mother's surname is Nguyễn, they  or their parents gave the full name for their child or their grandchild, which was me, as Phạm Nguyễn Ngọc Đạt.

Each of these Chữ Hán in your name has an "official" Korean version. This can be looked up, e.g. on Naver's Hanja Dictionary:

范 = Phạm = 범
阮 = Nguyễn = 완, 원
玉 = Ngọc = 옥
達 = Đạt = 달

범원옥달 does not "sound" like a very traditional Korean name because this four-character structure is rare. However, such a structure is attested among Koreans, including among relatively young people (e.g. singer and entertainer 황보혜정, born 1980; same surname as celebrated writer Hoàng Phủ Ngọc Tường).
옥달 as a name is not attested among recently registered names in Korea, but it is the English stage name of the female duo 옥상달빛.
To fit a more "general" surname + given name, you may consider re-arranging the syllables. But this is a very personal choice.

Can I have your recommendation of how to re-arranging the syllables of my own name? I'm about to work as an internship in a SW/ICT Korean company, that's great that I could integrate or immerse into their culture, one of which is that they are comfortable speaking Korean, even though they could or could not speak English.

I'd say something like 범달원 or 범원달, removing the 옥, would sound the most "Korean". 달원 is attested as a (very rare!) male given name. But again, this is a very personal choice (feel free to disregard it completely!).

Thank you for the useful information, and the website. I also find out that 범 is not a typical Korean surname, do you have any alternative suggestion to the surname, 范, or Phạm, Michaelyus?

@DatPham There are quite a few Koreans with the surname 범, e.g. poet 범대순, company president 범택균.
